# GitHub Jekyll cannot find posts

Tags: ruby, github, markdown, jekyll

I have a Markdown page index2.md as follow:

```
---
layout: plain
title: Index2
---

test Index2


<ul class="posts">
    {% for post in site.posts %}
      <li><span>{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</span> &raquo; <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

However this can't show my blog posts

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header>
        <h1>Nodeclipse.github.io</h1>
        <p>Resource for Nodeclipse developers</p>


        <p class="view"><a href="https://github.com/Nodeclipse">View My GitHub Profile</a></p>

      </header>
      <section>
            <div>            
            <p>test Index2</p>

<p>  <ul class="posts"></p>

<p>  </ul></p>

            </div>
      </section>
      <footer>
        <p><small>Hosted on GitHub Pages &mdash; Theme by <a href="https://github.com/orderedlist">orderedlist</a></small></p>
      </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="javascripts/scale.fix.js"></script>

  </body>
```

That is blog list is empty.

Comment: Your problem seems to be that your `ul` block is being interpreted as text. Are you using tabs in `index2.md`? If so, try converting your tabs to spaces.

Comment: Yes it was. However posts are still missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markdown is interpreting your indented HTML as content, and helpfully wrapping it in a  `<p>` tag for you.

Markdown will pass HTML through raw, which is what you want, but only if the starting and ending tags are not indented at all.  So, un-indent the opening and closing `<ul>` and `</ul>` tags, and Markdown will let the entire chunk of HTML go unmolested.  So it should look like this:

```
test Index2

<ul class="posts">
    {% for post in site.posts %}
        <li>
            <span>{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</span>
            &raquo;
            <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Take a look at sources for http://nodeclipse.github.io/index2
I have already corrected indentation.

Comment: I looked at your repo and it seems like your `_posts` dir has a leading space, which means Jekyll is not finding it.  run `mv \ _posts _posts` to fix it up, and finally enjoy Jekyll :)

Comment: Yes, that was exact problem.